# i cant run this app on my emulator CAN someone help me

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :app
> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
> It will be removed soon. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Configure project :react-native-check-app-install
> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
> It will be removed soon. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
> WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.5.2.
> Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
> To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :react-native-community_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-community_picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-push-notification:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
> Parsing json file: C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\android\app\google-services.json

> Task :react-native-check-app-install:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-sound:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-svg:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-webview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-voice_voice:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
246 actionable tasks: 246 executed
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules@react-native-community\async-storage\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\asyncstorage\AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\src\main\java\com\dieam\reactnativepushnotification\modules\RNPushNotificationHelper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\src\main\java\com\dieam\reactnativepushnotification\modules\RNPushNotification.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\react-native-sound\android\src\main\java\com\zmxv\RNSound\RNSoundModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-71:19: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/storyqube (aka com.storyqube:mipmap/storyqube) not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules@react-native-community\async-storage\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\asyncstorage\AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\src\main\java\com\dieam\reactnativepushnotification\modules\RNPushNotificationHelper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\src\main\java\com\dieam\reactnativepushnotification\modules\RNPushNotification.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\react-native-sound\android\src\main\java\com\zmxv\RNSound\RNSoundModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-71:19: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/storyqube (aka com.storyqube:mipmap/storyqube) not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s

```
at makeError (C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)      
at async Command.handleAction (C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

this is my log and I don't know whats wrong with my code but nothing is helping me

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your logs somewhere in your Android Manifest or your native android code you have called a resource `mipmap/storyqube` which comes from `com.storyqube` package. The build process fails because that file is simply not found. Could you check to see if you have a reference to it in your code?